# Hide fields from deriving (Show)

Tags: haskell, record

Imagine I have a data record with many fields:

```
data DataRecord = DataRecord {
    field1 :: String,
    field2 :: String,
    ...
} deriving (Show)
```

Is it possible to hide some fields from the `deriving (Show)` or do have to implement my own `show` function for `DataRecord`?

*Reason for my question:* When I have [cyclic dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696442/solve-cyclic-dependencies-in-haskell-data-records) between two data records both using `deriving (Show)` the `show` function would generate an infinite string.

Comment: Aside from developer debugging use, you probably want a Pretty instance instead of a show instance.  Either way, hand-writing the instance is your solution.

Comment: I have the case that I just need the ``show`` function for debugging purposes (for example in error messages for the ``error`` function).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Can you write a short answer that hand-writing the instance is the only solution so that I can accept it (and so that this question does not stay unanswered ;-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18600011.4) mentions your cyclic dependencies as unsuitable case:

> The derived `Read` and `Show` instances may be unsuitable for some uses. Some problems include:
>
> - Circular structures cannot be printed or read by these instances.

So you need to specify the instance by hand.

Comment: And, BTW, Show is a regular class, so writing an instance by hand is as simple as removing the "deriving Show" and writing `instance Show DataRecord where show dr = "DR " ++ field1 dr`