# Kotlin: Mutual assignments

Tags: kotlin, immutability

I want to set up two values that hold immutable references to each other. Example:

```
data class Person(val other: Person)
val jack = Person(jill), jill = Person(jack)   // doesn't compile
```

Note: `lateinit` doesn't seem to work with data class primary constructors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe nullable var?

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid nullable var. The rest of the application should consider this property immutable, once set.

Comment: This is a circular dependency problem: to create jack, I need jill, which in turn needs jack and so on.

Comment: @m0skit0 Correct. Any ideas?

Comment: @CSJ I think I did not explain myself correctly. What you want to do is **logically impossible** (more technically it requires an infinite amount of time), unless you want to relax your conditions.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, I see. In particular, a data class is supposed to define objects that are defined by their internal values .. and if those internal values are objects that are themselves defined by _their_ internal values ... and so on. It's values all the way down.

Comment: @m0skit0 Interesting fact: while it's logically impossible in Kotlin, it's possible in some other languages, e.g. in Haskell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696442/solve-cyclic-dependencies-in-haskell-data-records

Comment: @Ilya Still logically impossible in Haskell as well, however laziness and not having data classes solves the infinity cycle (Podcast data structure can actually be created without the episodes which are assigned later). Of course functional is more suited to dealing with infinity than OOP.

Answer (score 2):

You could get away with something like this:

```
class Person() {
    private var _other: Person? = null

    private constructor(_other: Person? = null) : this() {
        this._other = _other
    }

    val other: Person
        get() {
            if (_other == null) {
                _other = Person(this)
            }
            return _other ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
        }
}
```

And then you would be able to do:

```
val jack = Person()
val jill = jack.other
```

Using a `data class` here does not work for **multiple reasons**:

1. First because a `data class` can't have an empty constructor.
2. Even if that wasn't a problem, the generated methods would end up having a **cyclic dependency** and will fail in runtime with `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. So you'd have to overwrite `toString`, `equals`, etc. which kind of **defeats the purpose** of using `data class` in the first place.

Comment: Maybe a use case for `lazy` or `lateinit`?

Comment: I've re-written it using `lateinit` here: https://gist.github.com/jivimberg/3fd70a9bd69632c2275d14e24c0e7baa. And while I could convert the `Person?` type to `Person` I don't find it any more readable. 
More importantly I'm not sure what happens with the `isInitialized` check when there's concurrent access.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick (note, this is really a trick, you need a good reason to use it in real code).

Unfortunately it won't work with data classes, as they seem to be secured against this kind of hacks.

But if you have java-style classes, you may use two things to your advantage:

1. You can initialize `val`s in the constructor (same as with `final` in java)
2. You have access to `this` inside the constructor (and you may leak it outside if you really want)

Which means that you can create another `Person` **inside** the constructor of the first person and finalize the creation of both classes before the constructor finishes.

Once again: exposing `this` as I did below is a **bad** idea. When `otherFactory`  is called, it's parameter is only half-initialized. This may lead to nasty bugs, especially if you try to publish such reference in multithreaded environment.

A bit safer approach is to create both Persons inside the constructor of the first Person (you'll need to supply the fields of both entities as arguments). It's safer because you're in control of the code that uses half-initialized `this` reference.

```
class Person {
    val name: String
    val other: Person

    constructor(name: String, other: Person) {
        this.name = name
        this.other = other
    }

    // !! not very safe !!
    constructor(name: String, otherFactory: (Person) -> Person) {
        this.other = otherFactory(this)
        this.name = name
    }

    // a bit safer
    constructor(name: String, otherName: String) {
        this.other = Person(otherName, this)
        this.name = name
    }
}

val person1 = Person("first") {
    Person("second", it)
}

val person2 = person1.other

print(person1.name) // first
print(person2.name) // second

val person3 = Person("third", "fourth")
val person4 = person3.other

print(person3.name)
print(person4.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions everybody. I came up with an alternative and would like to hear your insights:

```
open class Person {
  open val other: Person by lazy { Person2(this) }
  class Person2(override val other: Person): Person()
}

val jack = Person()
val jill = jack.other
```

Here we have one person lazily instantiating the other on demand, using an internal subclass that implements `other` differently (i.e. it is just given it directly in its constructor).

Thoughts most welcome.